# Install Express-on-Railway JS error

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have this error when I try to install Express-on-Railway JS framework, please help:
https://github.com/1602/express-on-railway

```
npm ERR! error installing railway@0.1.7-8 Error: Unsupported
npm ERR! error installing railway@0.1.7-8     at checkEngine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:570:14)
npm ERR! error installing railway@0.1.7-8     at Array.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
npm ERR! error installing railway@0.1.7-8     at LOOP (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:13)
npm ERR! error installing railway@0.1.7-8     at chain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:20:4)
npm ERR! error installing railway@0.1.7-8     at installOne_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:548:3)
npm ERR! error installing railway@0.1.7-8     at installOne (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:488:3)
npm ERR! error installing railway@0.1.7-8     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:425:9
npm ERR! error installing railway@0.1.7-8     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:54:35
npm ERR! error installing railway@0.1.7-8     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR! error installing railway@0.1.7-8     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:54:11
npm ERR! Unsupported
npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: express@2.4.6
npm ERR! Required: {"node":">= 0.4.1 < 0.5.0"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.0.22","node":"v0.5.3-pre"}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.38-11-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "railway" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/gezope
npm ERR! node -v v0.5.3-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.22
...
npm not ok
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this would have been a comment but comment formatting is meh

To do this:

```
cd node (your node dir)
git tag (see the list - I believe 0.4.11 is last marked stable)
git checkout v0.4.11
./configure
make clean
make
make uninstall
make install
```

Then npm install express.

That will reset you to 0.4.11 and you should be ready to rock.

Answer (score 3):

express does not support 0.5

Please use 0.4.x

Comment: Thanks Raynos, great! How can I specify on Ubuntu which branch I wanna install and use by default? Is there any walkthrough or blogpost about it? Many thanks